# Unable to import numpy array properly from a text file

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, file-handling

I want to convert the string data type to numpy array of 2-D.

I'm importing a .txt file from a directory which contains:

```
[[18,1,2018,12,15],
[07,1,2018,12,15],
[03,1,2018,12,15]]
```

and the code is:

```
import numpy as np

f = open("/home/pi/timer_database.txt","r")
read = f.read()


x = np.array(list(read))
print(x.size)
print(type(x))
print(x.ndim)
```

The output is :

```
47
type <numpy.ndarray>
1
```

Please help me in this issue.

Comment: Are you generating the text file you are reading from?

Comment: The most common txt file format for sharing table data is `csv` - with just the values separated by a delimiter like comma.  The brackets don't add information, and just complicate the parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Use This code

```
import numpy as np
f = open("/home/pi/timer_database.txt","r")
read = f.read()
read = read.replace("[" , "")
read = read.replace("]" , "")
read = read.replace(",\n" , "\n")
f= open("New_Array.txt","w+")
f.write(read)
f.close()
Array = np.loadtxt("New_Array.txt" , delimiter=',')
print(Array)
```

Comment: when working with files, always use `with` so you don't forget to close a file like you did here. Also you don't need to generate garbage files, you can use `byteIO` and then feed the string to `loadtxt`

Comment: @JaiJanyani                                                                      Thanks for your help, though the file is not the replica of the original file.  
The output I'm getting is                                               ====================== RESTART: /home/pi/ac_auto_p1.py ======================            [[ 1.80000000e+01 1.00000000e+00 2.01800000e+03 1.20000000e+01 1.50000000e+01] [ 7.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 2.01800000e+03 1.20000000e+01 1.50000000e+01] [ 3.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 2.01800000e+03 1.20000000e+01 1.50000000e+01]]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ast` to evaluate your string, which is much easier than parsing the whole thing:

```
import ast
x=np.array(ast.literal_eval(read))
```

Or simply `eval`:

```
x=np.array(eval(read))
```

But this will raise an error because of the leading zeros you have, so first simply remove them:

```
import re
read=re.sub(r'\b0','',read)
```

Also if you are writing the file, it is much more advisable to use other approaches, first I would suggest to simply use `pickle`.

Comment: It showing syntax error: Traceback (most recent call last):
                                                          File "/home/pi/ac_auto_p1.py", line 14, in <module>
    x = np.array(ast.literal_eval(read))
                            File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 49, in literal_eval
    node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 37, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)
    File "<unknown>", line 2
    07,1,2018,12,15
     ^
                                       SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @MagicOak Did you even read the whole answer? Please do so, I've said you'll get this error because of your format and how to fix it.